# stl::map insert a value with a constraint

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I'm using an *stl::map* to store some key with a value. For my app, I need to to change the value of a key only if the current value is bigger then the previous one. To do this, I call 
*find()* to search if the key is already in the map and so to change its value, otherwise I call *insert()* to store the new key. Is there a way to do this kind of thing in an efficient way? Or to call only *insert()* with a custom constraint on the value?

Comment: Show some code so that I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: So, basically you want to do something like `myMap[key] = std::max(myMap[key], new_value)`?

Comment: @Zeta Yes, but only if the key is already stored in the map

Answer (score 4):

As per below, one of the insert overloads on the std::map returns a pair containing an iterator to the node and a bool. The bool tells you whether the insert was successful, or there was a dupe. If false, just update the value manually using the iterator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
  typedef std::map<std::string, int> TestMap;
  TestMap test;
  test.insert(std::make_pair("one", 1));

  std::pair<TestMap::iterator, bool> result =
      test.insert(std::make_pair("one", 2));

  if (!result.second)
  {
    // was a duplicate, so let's manually set the value on the existing
    // map entry

    result.first->second = 2;
  }

  std::cout << test.at("one") << std::endl; // outputs 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the best strategy! I only have to add a check of the previous value before to change it but it's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

If the map should be updated if the new value `T newval` is greater or equal to the previous `T oldval` and you use only values which are greater or equal to `T()` it's really simple:

```
myMap[key] = std::max(myMap[key],newval);
```

[`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) will return a reference to an element in the map, which will either be an already existing one or a new default constructed element (myMap[key] == `T()`).

Note that this solution uses `std::map::insert` behind the scene, but is a little bit easier to read if you only use non-negative values.

Comment: Thanks, it seems a good a strategy, maybe from the efficiency point of view is similar to the Troy's one.

Comment: @user1633717: The complexity / efficiency of both solutions should be the same. The `if` is hidden in `std::max`, and the `insert` is hidden in the call of `myMap[key]`. `insert` has a complexity of O(log N), and the important thing is the missing `find` call, which would also be O(log N).

Comment: Well, you have to search for `key` twice, so it's not that efficient.

Comment: @JohnB: Doesn't the compiler optimize the call of `operator[]`? Otherwise you could just use `value_type & myelement = myMap[key]; myelement = std::max(myelement,newval);`

Comment: What does this do if the key is not found?

Comment: It will automatically insert a default constructed element in the map. I already covered that in my answer :)

Comment: Indeed. "`operator []` always increases the map size by one if the key is not found." Funny. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Call `lower_bound` to search for the element. It will give you the next greater key if it does not exist. If the key does not exist, go back one step with the iterator, and then you can call `insert` with parameter `position` being provided, which reduces time to search for the correct position to insert (to almost zero probably, as you provide the correct position and `map` is ordered)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I think the strategy of Troy is better, because I have to call only one time the insert().